# Debo completar esta directiva o no?<?php echo dirname(__FILE__); ?>

Tags: php, linux

Esto lo encontré como ejemplo en internet para saber la ruta donde me encuentro en linux (donde tenga el archivo. para sacar la ruta absoluta):

```
<?php
echo dirname(__FILE__);
?>
```

Ahora mi pregunta es: ¿qué tengo que completar lo que está entre paréntesis? ¿O lo pongo así como está?

Comment: Prueba, así sabrás si te falta algo o no.

Answer (score 1):

No entiendo que quieres decir con completar pero si la llamas asi como esta si funciona, ya que la función `dirname()` devuelve la ruta de un directorio padre, si le pasas como parametro `__FILE__` devolverá la ruta del archivo php donde se esta llamando la función. Si por ejemplo tu archivo esta en /var/www/html/sistema/archivo.php

`echo dirname(__FILE__);`

Mostrara como resultado /var/www/html/sistema/.

Answer (score 0):

Si te refieres a que si `echo` necesita paréntesis como si fuera una función: no, no los necesita porque no es una función, si no una construcción del lenguaje (como `require`, `include`, `case`, etc):

```
<?php
/* Esto es innecesario */
echo (dirname(__FILE__));
```

El código que has usado envía directamente la ruta al navegador, no la almacena para su posterior uso. Si quieres almacenarla para usarla posteriormente lo que que falta es asignarla a una variable, y no poner paréntesis ni nada similar.

Haciendo lo que te muestro a continuación podrás abrir archivos haciendo uso de esa ruta base almacenada en la variable:

```
<?php
/* Almacenamos la ruta del script en la variable $ruta */
$ruta = dirname(__FILE__);
/* Hacemos uso de la variable $ruta para acceder a un archivo que
  hay en el mismo directorio que el script */
$datos = file_get_contents($ruta . '/archivo.txt');
```

NOTA: A partir de PHP 5.3 tienes disponible la [constante predefinida `__DIR__`](http://php.net/language.constants.predefined#constant.dir). A fecha de tu pregunta la versión más vieja con soporte era la versión [PHP 5.5](http://php.net/eol), por lo que deberías usar dicha macro en vez de `dirname(__FILE__)`.

```
<?php
/* Ya no es necesario almacenar la ruta base en ninguna variable */
$datos = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/archivo.txt');
```